# API returns different Object Types for different scenarios

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am consuming an API in Java Web App . API returns JSON and it has field 'Translations' for each Question . When Translations are available , it is returned as Nested Object type. If no translations are available , it is returned as empty Array . I am using Jackson deserializer for deserializing the result .

```
 {
     "result" :{"QI": {
            "Question": "Select City",
            "Option": {
                "1": {
                    "Display": "Washington DC"
                },
                "2": {
                    "Display": "New Delhi"
                },
                "3": {
                    "Display": "London"
                }
            },
            "Transalations": []
        },
        "Q2": {
            "Question": "Select Country",
            "Option": {
                "1": {
                    "Display": "India"
                },
                "2": {
                    "Display": "USA"
                },
                "3": {
                    "Display": "UK"
                }
            },
            "Transalations": {
                "ZH-T": {
                    "Question": "選擇國家",
                    "Option": {
                        "1": {
                            "Display": "印度"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "Display": "美國"
                        },
                        "3": {
                            "Display": "英國"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ES-ES": {
                    "Question": "Seleccionar país",
                    "Option": {
                        "1": {
                            "Display": "India"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "Display": "Estados Unidos"
                        },
                        "3": {
                            "Display": "Reino Unido"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

I am mapping the result field in a Response Class using Map Object:

```
 Map<String, Object> result
```

When I try to get Translations after getting "Q1" from result using

```
Map<String,Object> translations = (Map<String,Object>)questionDetails.get("Transalations");
```

I get ClassCastException stating that ArrayList cannot be converted to LinkedHashMap whenever I encounter a question with no translations .

**"Transalations": []**

How do I map these two different objects . I am aware of **instanceOf** but do not want to use it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'instanceOf' is the only option to do that in java. Jackson uses the same approach under the hood to resolve numbers, objects, etc.

Also you can specify a class for your response and create custom deserializer, that should use 'instanceOf' anyway.